# detecting an incoming sms in a windows mobile application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I want my app to respond in case the user recieves an sms. The app does not need to access the content of the message,it should only detect if an sms has been recieved. I googled the problem but couldn't find any relevant resources. Can anyone help me regarding this problem? Is such a functionality possible in a windows phone app?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Look in object browser...

I found this:
Windows.Phone.Networking.NetworkOperators.SmsInterceptor

MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj585389%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible on Windows Phone 7. The Windows.Phone.Networking.NetworkOperators.SmsInterceptor recommended byt Tiz states it is for Windows Phone 8.